# How to make an inundation map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, flood

My task is to calculate the area available for specific plant species in a natural reserve that has been reconnected to the tidal influence.

First step is to create an inundation map for a natural reserve. 
I have a height map in .dxf format (annotation,point, polyline,polygone and multipatch layers). I can see the height of the points in the attributes layer. 
I have available the data (for one year) for the tide levels from a connected tide gauge for the fluctuating water level. I'm now combining this with the plant preferences for inundation time. I expect to get a result like for species 1 the height between 1.5 an 1.7 meter is suitable, for species 2 between 1.7 and 1.8 and so on.

How do I implement this in the map and find the total suitable area for each species? I am running Arcgis 9.3 with the Spatial Analyst and 3D Analyst extensions.

Comment: Version 9 is pretty outdated at this point, but beyond that there are some significant differences between 9.1, 9.2, and 9.3. Can you specify exactly which version you have? Also if you have any extensions available, like Spatial Analyst? What is the source/software of the .dgf file (I'm not recognizing the extension right off though others might)? You may be wanting a raster out of that rather than a shapefile. You can use the **edit** button at the bottom left of your post to add clarification to the question.

Comment: This is a bit broad and I imagine there a couple of ways to go about it. First, you'll want to get a DEM of the area. I'm not sure what all you have in your dxf, but you could use contour lines or points to generate one. With that I can think of a couple of approaches. One would be to determine the inundation time/elevations (ie sea +1-2m is under four hours) and then use that to Reclassify your DEM into ranges that show inundation time and calc class areas. You could also do this with a DEM and a bunch of surfaces at given tide heights using 3D Analyst.